# can someone expalin me the java program?

Tags: java, arrays

what is the output and explain in detail, as I am very confused in `args.length`.

```
class check 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println(args[args.length-2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it with different amounts of command line parameters and be amazed!

Comment: Perhaps read [Oracle's Arrays tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: can u explain me the code asss ia m very confused

Comment: `length` is a property of the array, its value is the array's length.

Comment: `args` are the arguments (parameters) you pass into the program...`.length` will give you the number of parameters. So if I pass in 2 parameters the output will be `args[2-2]` or `args[0]` which is the first parameter passed in. You will get an exception if you pass in less than 2 `args`.

Comment: Please read the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. You should at least have tried something yourself, such as running the code snippet. There are also online IDEs available such as http://ideone.com/ which are often sufficient for this kind of code snippets (https://www.compilejava.net/ also supports command line parameters)

Comment: i didn't understand the line "So if I pass in 2 parameters the output will be args[2-2] or args[0] which is the first parameter passed in. You will get an exception if you pass in less than 2 args." can u plz explain me.

Answer (score 3):

It prints this:

```
java check a b c
> b
```

for single variable (`java check a`) it prints error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at check.main(check.java:6)
```